# Getting value from clicked item in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a loop in my MVC-project whick generates a list of open-timeslots:

```
foreach (var item in Model.LedigaTider)
    {


        <a id="@item">
            <div class="table-time" id="@item.ToShortTimeString()">
                @item.ToShortTimeString() - @item.AddMinutes(ViewBag.BehTid).ToShortTimeString()
            </div>
        </a>
```

The user is suppose to click on one of the time-slots and I need to store the value of that timeslot in an input-textbox...I´ve been trying som different Js-functions but they have failed due to the fact that its beeing executed within the foreach-loop.
Thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

assuming you have a textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="txtBox"/>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('.table-time').click(function(){

$('input#txtBox').val($(this).html());

})
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind ... I formatted your answer just a little bit.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks alot both of you!